# Proxy Error 502 when uploading larger files with IE8

Tags: apache, internet-explorer-8, reverse-proxy

I am having trouble uploading files with IE8 to a remote web server over an Apache reverse proxy. I used Fiddler to track the request and response. Submitting a form with a .txt attached roughly larger than 17KB, I get the following error: Proxy Error 502.  Submitting a smaller version of the same file through the same form works.  **What causes this and why doesn't it happen with other browsers?**

Update -- I used fiddler to remove the line `Cache-Control: no-cache` which I noticed isn't used by Firefox and it worked.  Not sure how I'm going to fix it though, so question still stands.

**Failure Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 502 Proxy Error
Date: Tue, 17 Sep 2013 14:16:56 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.3 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1c
Content-Length: 468
Keep-Alive: timeout=30, max=96
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>502 Proxy Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Proxy Error</h1>
<p>The proxy server received an invalid
response from an upstream server.<br />
The proxy server could not handle the request <em><a href="/this/is/not/the/real/url.ajax">POST&nbsp;/this/is/not/the/real/url.ajax</a></em>.<p>
Reason: <strong>Error reading from remote server</strong></p></p>
</body></html>
```

**Failed Request Header**

```
POST https://www.foo.com/blah.ajax HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-shockwave-flash, */*
Referer: https://www.mysite.com/blah.html
Accept-Language: en-us
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7dd2702f50124
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: www.mysite.com
Content-Length: 412501
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
(cookies and data removed for brevity...)
```

**Successful Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 17 Sep 2013 15:10:34 GMT
Server: myServer
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 59
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Tue, 17 Sep 2013 16:10:34 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Keep-Alive: timeout=30, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
{
   "received":"what I expected"
}
```

**Successful Request Header**

```
POST https://www.foo.com/blah.ajax HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-shockwave-flash, */*
Referer: https://www.mysite.com/blah.html
Accept-Language: en-us
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7dd983550124
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: www.mysite.com
Content-Length: 1287
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
(cookies and data removed for brevity...)
```

**Update 2**
Starting to get clearer.  My Apache reverse proxy server threw out this error, which based on Googling seems to indicate that the connection was close prematurely between the proxy and the server.

```
[Mon Sep 16 17:06:24.983899 2013] [proxy:error] [pid 14796:tid 140093427799808] 
[client myipaddress:port] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by 
/the/requested/page, referer: 
https://www.mySite.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commented out these lines on our Apache server's proxy config file and the problem stopped occurring.  If anyone can explain why this happened, I will give credit to them, because I honestly don't know why this fixed the problem.  From Googling, I get the sense that something was closing the server-proxy connection prematurely, so the `nokeepalive` directive may have been the problem.  I'm a bit worried this solution does not address the root problem.

```
# SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
# SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
```

### Update

I did some research in the [apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#envsettings).  It looks like our origin server may not "properly implement keepalives or HTTP/1.1".

Comment: Hello @alexma- did you discover the issue with keepalives or HTTP/1.1?

Comment: @mike_butak I don’t believe so, but this happened 7ish years ago.